# What tests would be suitable for a survey with mixed question types?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, spearman-rho

I have done a survey (n=138) on student preferences of homework types. It's my first time attempting anything of the sort and I have a high schooler's understanding of math and statistics.

My null hypotheses are:

1. Tasks that students most liked have no significant relationship with tasks
   that students learned the most from
2. Tasks that students learned the most from have no significant relationship with tasks classed as higher order learning
3. Final year students' homework experiences have no significant relationship to their preparedness to join the industry

Most of the questions were "Please rank the item types in order" and "Please tick all that apply" questions. 3) uses a multi-row Likert scale. I have decided to use Spearman's rho to prove the correlation for 1). The students are split into 4 year levels so I thought of using the Kruskal-Wallis H test as well. It was my first time designing a survey. Did I screw myself over by using too many question types? What other statistical tests should I apply?